# Multiple definition of first defined here gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, include, multiple-definition-error

I have these files

```
consumer.cpp
consumer.hpp
defines.hpp
main.cpp
makefile
producer.cpp
producer.hpp
```

here's the file defines.hpp

```
#ifndef DEFINES_HPP
#define DEFINES_HPP

#include <cassert>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <queue>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t set_queue_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

std::queue<int> q;

#endif // DEFINES_HPP
```

This defines.hpp file is included in the producer.hpp and consumer.hpp. producer.hpp and consumer.hpp files respectively included to producer.cpp and consumer.cpp and yet to main.cpp.
When compiling I get an error.

```
g++ -o main producer.cpp consumer.cpp main.cpp producer.hpp consumer.hpp defines.hpp -lpthread -ggdb
/tmp/ccctuRp7.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::destroy(int*)':
/home/vardan/test/consumer.cpp:8: multiple definition of `set_queue_mutex'
/tmp/cciGccft.o:/home/vardan/test/producer.cpp:8: first defined here
/tmp/ccctuRp7.o: In function `std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::front()':
/home/vardan/test/consumer.cpp:12: multiple definition of `condition_var'
/tmp/cciGccft.o:/home/vardan/test/producer.cpp:11: first defined here
/tmp/ccctuRp7.o: In function `global::consumer::entry_point(void*)':
/home/vardan/test/consumer.cpp:17: multiple definition of `q'
/tmp/cciGccft.o:/home/vardan/test/producer.cpp:17: first defined here
/tmp/ccKCxptM.o: In function `main':
/home/vardan/test/main.cpp:8: multiple definition of `set_queue_mutex'
/tmp/cciGccft.o:/home/vardan/test/producer.cpp:8: first defined here
/tmp/ccKCxptM.o: In function `main':
/home/vardan/test/main.cpp:13: multiple definition of `condition_var'
/tmp/cciGccft.o:/home/vardan/test/producer.cpp:11: first defined here
/tmp/ccKCxptM.o: In function `main':
/home/vardan/test/main.cpp:25: multiple definition of `q'
/tmp/cciGccft.o:/home/vardan/test/producer.cpp:17: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Here is my makefile

```
main : producer.cpp consumer.cpp main.cpp producer.hpp consumer.hpp defines.hpp
    g++ -o $@ $^ -lpthread -ggdb
.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -rf main *.swf *.o
```

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In C++ (as well as in C) there is a difference between *declaring* and *defining* things like variables. What you are doing in the header file is *defining* the variables, which means that every source file that includes the header file will have the definitions.

In the header file you should only *declare* the variables, and then in a single source file define them.

So in the header file do e.g.

```
extern pthread_mutex_t set_queue_mutex;
extern pthread_cond_t  condition_var;

extern std::queue<int> q;
```

And then in a single source file put the definitions (what you have now).

Comment: `extern` that was the keyword that made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here because I had a similar problem that wasn't quite answered here. Whenever I would delete the method in question, I would get `undefined reference to *method-name*` and whenever I would add it back in, I would get `multiple definition of *method-name*`. I solved my problem (after an hour!) by simply running my `make clean`. It turns out that my `.o` files were messed up, and the `Makefile` did not update them properly like it was supposed to with `make` or `make run`.

Not exactly your problem, but hopefully someone stumbles across this who needs it.